# Change the UIButton Image when tapped multiple times

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

My requirement is to change the UIButton image for three different states. As of now when I tap the button for the first two times (first two states), it works. But when I tap for the third time or when it triggers my third state, the second image still seems to appear. How can and solve this issue?  My code is below.

```
@IBAction func repeateButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    let image = UIImage(named : "repeat_one")
    let image2 = UIImage(named : "repeat")

    if(playerRepeatMode == RepeatModes.NO_REPEAT){
        playerRepeatMode = RepeatModes.REPEAT_LIST
        self.repeatButton.setBackgroundImage(image2, for: .normal)
        self.repeatButton.backgroundColor = buttonToggleColor
    }
    else if(playerRepeatMode == RepeatModes.REPEAT_LIST){
        playerRepeatMode = RepeatModes.REPEAT
        self.repeatButton.setBackgroundImage(image, for: .normal)
    //    self.repeatButton.setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "repeat_one"), for: UIControlState.normal)
        self.repeatButton.backgroundColor = buttonToggleColor
    }else{
        playerRepeatMode = RepeatModes.NO_REPEAT
        self.repeatButton.setBackgroundImage(image2, for: .normal)
        self.repeatButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }
}
```

Comment: You only have 2 images - how do you expect to see 3 different ones?

Comment: No for the third instance also I use the first image, but changing the output of the click event and the background color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

**Answer after question edit**

A couple tips to make it easier to debug...

1. Add comments
2. Use variable names that make sense - e.g. `imgRepeat` instead of `image2` for an image named "repeat"

The following code works fine for me - assuming the images have transparent areas to show the background color.

```
@IBAction func repeateButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    let imgRepeatOne = UIImage(named : "repeat_one")
    let imgRepeat = UIImage(named : "repeat")


    if (playerRepeatMode == RepeatModes.NO_REPEAT) {

        // currently NO_REPEAT, changing to REPEAT_LIST
        playerRepeatMode = RepeatModes.REPEAT_LIST

        // set BackroundImage to "repeat"
        self.repeatButton.setBackgroundImage(imgRepeat, for: .normal)

        // set BackgroundColor to buttonToggleColor
        self.repeatButton.backgroundColor = buttonToggleColor

    } else if (playerRepeatMode == RepeatModes.REPEAT_LIST) {

        // currently REPEAT_LIST, changing to REPEAT
        playerRepeatMode = RepeatModes.REPEAT

        // set BackroundImage to "repeat_one"
        self.repeatButton.setBackgroundImage(imgRepeatOne, for: .normal)

        // set BackgroundColor to buttonToggleColor
        self.repeatButton.backgroundColor = buttonToggleColor

    } else {

        // currently REPEAT, changing to NO_REPEAT
        playerRepeatMode = RepeatModes.NO_REPEAT

        // set BackroundImage to "repeat"
        self.repeatButton.setBackgroundImage(imgRepeat, for: .normal)

        // set BackgroundColor to clear
        self.repeatButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    }

}
```

---

**Original Answer**

I think the issue is that you are using `.setImage()` in one place, but `.setBackgroundImage()` in the other two places.

That would be fine, assuming you *want* `image2` to be used as background and `image` to be used as the button image, but you need to **clear** the other property.

So, where you use the background image:

```
    self.repeatButton.setBackgroundImage(image2, for: .normal)

    // also *clear* the button image
    self.repeatButton.setImage(nil, for: .normal)
```

and, where you use the button image:

```
    self.repeatButton.setImage(image, for: .normal)

    // also *clear* the background image
    self.repeatButton.setBackgroundImage(nil, for: .normal)
```

Comment: i did but still didnt solve the issue, plus i updated the code

Comment: figured it out with your tip